# SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) C++ Pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

Ok this is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Nodo{
public:
    Nodo *siguiente,*anterior;
    string Nombre,Curso,Posicion;
    int carnet;
    Nodo(){
        siguiente=anterior=NULL;
        Nombre=Curso="";
        carnet=0;
    }
};
class ListaCircular{
public:
    Nodo *PrimerNodo,*UltimoNodo;    
    ListaCircular(){
        *PrimerNodo->siguiente=*UltimoNodo;
    }
};

int main(){
    ListaCircular *a=new ListaCircular();
    cout<<a->PrimerNodo->siguiente<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When i try to run it it says "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" but "RUN FAILED", and when i debug it the SIGSEGV message appears, the line that seems to have an error is:

```
*PrimerNodo->siguiente=*UltimoNodo;
```

but if i run the program again without the lines:

```
ListaCircular *a=new ListaCircular();
cout<<a->PrimerNodo->siguiente<<endl;
```

then the program have a succesfull build and run.

How can I make that "cout" successfuly?

Comment: You don't have any Nodos, only pointers to Nodos.

Comment: What exactly do you want it to print?

Comment: Actualy the cout is not important, is like a way to be sure that PrimerNodo->siguiente is pointing to UltimoNodo, the real fact is that I must point PrimerNodo->siguiente to UltimoNodo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the constructor of this class:

```
class ListaCircular{
public:
    Nodo *PrimerNodo,*UltimoNodo;    
    ListaCircular(){
        *PrimerNodo->siguiente=*UltimoNodo;
    }
};
```

you are trying to dereference uninitialized pointer `PrimerNodo`, which produces **undefined behavior**. In your case it results to *segmentation fault* (which is actually good, because otherwise this kind of error might be hard to find).

One of the possible solutions is to create these objects of type `Nodo` within the constructor's body:

```
ListaCircular(){
    PrimerNodo = new Nodo();
    UltimoNodo = new Nodo();
    PrimerNodo->siguiente = UltimoNodo;
}
```

also note that this line:

```
cout << a->PrimerNodo->siguiente << endl;
```

will print the address of the memory that `a->PrimerNodo->siguiente` points to.

Answer (score 1):

I am still kinda of new to c++, so it might be that i am wrong, but shouldn't it be `Primernodo->siguiente=Ultimonodo`? in the `ListaCircular` class..

Also, what exactly are you trying to print? Are you trying to print the object, or what? you might want to add another '->' after "Siguiente, like " `cout<<<a->PrimerNodo->siguiente->toString<< endl;` or similar..

Comment: please do not downvote this answer. The poster does not have enough privileges to post as comment!

Answer (score 0):

it should be:

`PrimerNodo->siguiente=UltimoNodo`

But, `UltimoNodo` is not initialized, so dereferencing it could be illegal(UB).

Comment: @RobertoHernandez that is because the `UltimoNodo` is not initialized. Please initialize it like this: `UltimoNodo = new Nodo()`

Answer (score 0):

Define a new Nodo linking function:-

```
void Nodo::SetSiguiente(Nodo*sig){
    siguiente=sig;
    sig->anterior=this;
}
```

Fix the constructor:-

```
ListaCircular(){
    PrimerNodo = new Nodo;
    UltimoNodo = new Nodo;

    PrimerNodo->SetSiguiente(UltimoNodo);
    UltimoNodo->SetSiguiente(PrimerNodo);
}
```

Comment: if I change `UltimoNodo` or `PrimerNodo` .. the other will change as well. Bad way to do it! :-)

Comment: If it is going to be circular in both directions you'll have to write a function to change a node, that moves all the pointers about.